# Hide the keyboard with return key for an UITextField in a tableviewcell

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a view with a embedded tableview in it in which i have a UITextField and I want to hide the keyboard when I press the done button

[image: my Storyboard]

My Code is the following:

**My tableViewController:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "playerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerNameTableViewCell else {fatalError("Wrong type of cell")}

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.playerName.delegate = self

        return cell
}
```

**My cell:**

```
class PlayerNameTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerName: UITextField!

    @IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()

    }

}
```

But nothing happens when I press the done button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following function to the class that implements the UITextFieldDelegate:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

Comment: It worked I had tried it but I had added it in the CellClass in stead of the tableViewControllerClass.

Comment: I was already editing my answer, but glad you figured it out. If your UITableViewCell implements is your UITextFieldDelegate, then you can remove the delegate assignment in the tableViewController class and move it do the `didMoveToSuperview` function of your cell. Then it would be `self.playerName.delegate = self`